# Get Point from Another Table based on Category and Value Range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, join

I am trying to get a column which specify the points by comparing the value from original table to min and max value from another table. I have a main table, which consists of few columns of values and the respective point column to be inserted. Here is the example:

```
Main table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User   | Department |  BU  |  Revenue | Revenuepoint | Profit |  Profitpoint |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A      | 1000000    | 101  |  400     |              | 200    |              |
| B      | 1000001    | 101  |  300     |              | 100    |              |
| C      | 1000000    | 102  |  350     |              | 150    |              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Point table
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Category| Department |  BU  |  Fromvalue  | Tovalue | Point  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Revenue | 1000000    | 101  |  0          | 200     | 1      |
| Revenue | 1000000    | 101  |  201        | 400     | 2      |
| Revenue | 1000000    | 102  |  0          | 300     | 1      |
| Revenue | 1000000    | 102  |  301        | 400     | 2      |
| Revenue | 1000001    | 101  |  0          | 200     | 1      |
| Revenue | 1000001    | 101  |  201        | 400     | 2      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 101  |  0          | 100     | 1      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 101  |  101        | 300     | 2      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 102  |  0          | 50      | 1      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 102  |  51         | 200     | 2      |
| Profit  | 1000001    | 101  |  0          | 50      | 1      |
| Profit  | 1000001    | 101  |  51         | 200     | 2      |
----------------------------------------------------------------


Expected table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User   | Department |  BU  |  Revenue | Revenuepoint | Profit |  Profitpoint |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A      | 1000000    | 101  |  400     |       2      | 200    |       2      |
| B      | 1000001    | 101  |  300     |       2      | 40     |       1      |
| C      | 1000000    | 102  |  350     |       2      | 150    |       2      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Department and BU need to match and the RevenuePoint needs to take the records where the Category = Revenue, same as ProfitPoint.

I tried a few ways that i found in here, but most not as complex as mine so i have no idea how to move from here.

This is the code that i tried

```
SELECT 
a.User, 
a.Department, 
a.BU, 
a.Revenue, 
(SELECT MAX(b.Point) from Point b WHERE a.Revenue BETWEEN b.fromvalue and b.tovalue) as Revenuepoint,
b.Point as Revenuepoint,
a.Profit, 
(SELECT MAX(b.Point) from Point b WHERE a.Profit BETWEEN b.fromvalue and b.tovalue) as Profitpoint
FROM Sales a
```

Comment: I think your first step is to look at your sub-queries that are retrieving the MAX(<point value>).  Do you believe those sub-queries are correctly looking at only the relevant "Revenue" or "Profit" records, to compare the values and get the points?  If not, then what needs to be done to resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CROSS APPLY a PIVOT table -

MSDN Documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

I populated your data using this code -

```
CREATE TABLE #sales
(
    [User] CHAR(1)
  , Department INT
  , BU INT
  , Revenue INT
  , RevenuePoint INT
  , Profit INT
  , ProfitPoint INT
);

INSERT INTO #sales
VALUES
('A', 1000000, 101, 400, NULL, 200, NULL)
, ('B', 1000001, 101, 300, NULL, 100, NULL)
, ('C', 1000000, 102, 350, NULL, 150, NULL);

CREATE TABLE #point
(
    Category VARCHAR(10)
  , Department INT
  , BU INT
  , FromValue INT
  , ToValue INT
  , Point INT
);

INSERT INTO #point
VALUES
('Revenue', 1000000, 101, 0, 200, 1)
, ('Revenue', 1000000, 101, 201, 400, 2)
, ('Revenue', 1000000, 102, 0, 300, 1)
, ('Revenue', 1000000, 102, 301, 400, 2)
, ('Revenue', 1000001, 101, 0, 200, 1)
, ('Revenue', 1000001, 101, 201, 400, 2)
, ('Profit', 1000000, 101, 0, 100, 1)
, ('Profit', 1000000, 101, 101, 300, 2)
, ('Profit', 1000000, 102, 0, 50, 1)
, ('Profit', 1000000, 102, 51, 200, 2)
, ('Profit', 1000001, 101, 0, 50, 1)
, ('Profit', 1000001, 101, 51, 200, 1);
```

Then by running this, you get your desired dataset -

```
SELECT s.[User]
     , s.Department
     , s.BU
     , s.Revenue
     , display.Revenue
     , s.Profit
     , display.Profit
FROM #sales AS s
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT p_pvt.Profit
         , p_pvt.Revenue
    FROM
    (
        SELECT p.Category
             , p.Point
        FROM #point AS p
        WHERE s.Department = p.Department
              AND s.BU = p.BU
              AND
              (
                  (
                      s.Revenue
              BETWEEN p.FromValue AND p.ToValue
                      AND p.Category = 'Revenue'
                  )
                  OR
                  (
                      s.Profit
              BETWEEN p.FromValue AND p.ToValue
                      AND p.Category = 'Profit'
                  )
              )
    ) AS p_root
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Point)
        FOR Category IN (Revenue, Profit)
    ) AS p_pvt
) AS display;
```

The UPDATE statement would look like this -

```
UPDATE s
SET s.RevenuePoint = display.Revenue
  , s.ProfitPoint = display.Profit
FROM #sales AS s
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT p_pvt.Profit
         , p_pvt.Revenue
    FROM
    (
        SELECT p.Category
             , p.Point
        FROM #point AS p
        WHERE s.Department = p.Department
              AND s.BU = p.BU
              AND
              (
                  (
                      s.Revenue
              BETWEEN p.FromValue AND p.ToValue
                      AND p.Category = 'Revenue'
                  )
                  OR
                  (
                      s.Profit
              BETWEEN p.FromValue AND p.ToValue
                      AND p.Category = 'Profit'
                  )
              )
    ) AS p_root
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Point)
        FOR Category IN (Revenue, Profit)
    ) AS p_pvt
) AS display;
```

The result table is as follows -

```
User Department  BU          Revenue     RevenuePoint     Profit      ProfitPoint
---- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
A    1000000     101         400         2           200         2
B    1000001     101         300         2           100         1
C    1000000     102         350         2           150         2
```